# angularjs-datetime-picker formatting from Json object

Tags: c#, angularjs

I asked the question to generic so i made a specific case:

Cant implement https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-datetime-picker
I have a class Employee with a List of timeRegistrations.

```
<link href="~/Content/Angular-Datetimepicker/angularjs-datetime-picker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Content/Angular-Datetimepicker/angularjs-datetime-picker.min.js"></script>
```

I added this to my Module

```
var app; 
(function () { app = angular.module( "WorksheetEdit", ['angularjs-datetime-picker']);
```

I have the following in my HTML:
This is inside a repeater.

```
<input datetime-picker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ng-model="timeregistration.StartDate" />
```

I'm using a $http.get() to return the data from C# controller.
To serialise i'm using :

```
    string isoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst);
    return Content(isoJson, "application/json");
```

The problem here seems to be i cant format the date.
It keeps this notation: **2018-02-01T00:00:00**

Comment: You can find many guides. What have you tried?

Comment: try to find the solution from google or let us know what you have tried for it?

Comment: Choose the most reliable library you have tried. Ask a specific question about it. Show us what you want and what you have try (code [mcve]) , and why it's not ok. Then you will have a answereable question. For now it's like asking someone to fix your car with out showing the car. just by telling:"I went to few repairs but meh.."Gasoline and manual by the way"

Comment: Could you post the full JSON data that comes from the server.